# go time.Now() not giving proper time

Tags: go, time

I am running this simple go program and expecting to get different time (a difference of 3-second period) for starting and shutdown logs as I have given sleep of 3 seconds, but I am getting same time.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

const (
    logInfo = "INFO"
    logWarning = "WARNING"
    logError = "ERROR"
)

type logEntry struct {
    time time.Time
    severity string
    message string
}

var myLogChannel = make(chan logEntry, 50)

func main() {
    go logger()
    myLogChannel <- logEntry{ time.Now(), logInfo, "App is starting" }
    time.Sleep(3 * time.Second)
    fmt.Println("Time is :", time.Now().Format("2006-01-02 15:04:06"))
    myLogChannel <- logEntry{ time.Now(), logInfo, "App is shuting down" }
    time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
}
func logger() {
    for entry := range myLogChannel {
        fmt.Printf("%v : [%v]: %v\n", entry.time.Format("2006-01-02 15:04:06"),entry.severity, entry.message)
    }
}
```

Output:
On my system (running under cygwin env):
2020-10-12 11:03:20 : [INFO]: App is starting
Time is : 2020-10-12 11:03:20
2020-10-12 11:03:20 : [INFO]: App is shuting down

On playground:
2009-11-10 23:00:09 : [INFO]: App is starting
Time is : 2009-11-10 23:00:09
2009-11-10 23:00:09 : [INFO]: App is shuting down

Comment: I changed the time.Now().Format as:
time.Now().Format("2006-01-02 T 15:04:05")
Now it's giving correct results. I am a toddler in go..so need to check more about this.

Comment: A better way to check time difference will be  t:= time.Now(); and then check time elapsed as time.Since(t)

Comment: Note that the Playground has no real time.

Answer (score 5):

Your time format is wrong. 06 is the last two digits of the year, so it is printing `20` for 2020. Use the format: `2006-01-02 15:04:05`